# Allowed memory size exhausted in FlattenException Symfony

Tags: symfony

i got this error at least 20 times each minute on my production server logs.

My website is getting down when visitors number arrives to ~50.

Any suggestion?

> [Fri Dec 14 23:52:32.339692 2018] [:error] [pid 12588] [client
>   81.39.153.171:55104] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in
>   /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FlattenException.php
>   on line 269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your production, you don't need to debug component, for reducing memory use composer with --no-dev --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader.
If you can access your server via ssh, check memory consuming.
My suggestion if you have 50 visitors at the same time, This is a good time to upgrade the server.
Also, you can try to reduce max_execution_time to open some more memory.

Comment: My question thats it, why Symfony is using debug components on my prodution enviroment?

Comment: If you don't put --no-dev to composer, it will automatically install dev repositories as well.

Comment: Its okay, but why Symfony uses if i'm using app.php instead app_dev.php?

Comment: Can be two reason, in app.php if appKernel is flagged true after env, its mean debug is true. or even it can be debug its flaged false but autoloaders are loading all installed vendors.

Comment: adding `set :composer_install_flags, '--no-dev --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader'` to my capistrano deploy file it solved. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The question is very vague, so this won't be accurate...

Your limit is 512 Mb, and still not enough, so that only leaves a few possibilities.

First check the logs to see if these errors are tied to any specific URL.

(If you don't have adequate logging, I recommend using Rollbar, it has a monolog handler, and takes only a few minutes to wire up. It is also free.)

You mentioned the visitor count... I'm not sure if it has anything to do with this. What kind of webserver are you using?

Check for the usual suspects:

- Infinite loops, recursions without an exit condition.
- Large files (upload and download mostly)
- Statistical modules with complex queries and a high limit are also a good place to check.